# Random variable and distribution function

Tags: random-variables, density-function, cumulative-distribution-functions

I had this problem which I had no idea how to solve.

**Random variable X has a cumulative distribution function with the density:** 
$$f(x)=\left\{ \begin{array}{l}
c(1+x)&x∈[0,1] \\ 
0&x∉[0,1] \end{array} \right.$$

A) Define the unknown constant c and the distribution function of X
B) Define the Expected value of the random variable $1+\frac{X^2}{2}$
C) Random variable Z is given by $Z=\sqrt X -1$ find the distribution function of Z

For A) I understand that to calculate the constant c we need to integrate:
$$1=\int f(x)dx = \int_0^1 c(1+x)dx = c[x]_0^1+c[\frac{x^2}{2}]_0^1=1c+\frac{1}{2}c=\frac{3}{2}c => c=2/3$$
And for the distribution function:
$$D(x)=P(X<=x)=\int_{-∞}^xf(t)dt = \int_0^x\frac{2}{3}(1+t)dt=...=\frac{2}{3}(x+\frac{x^2}{2})$$
And afterwards I'm lost. Not even sure on the beforehand things.

Comment: By calculation of $D(x)$ you substituted $c=3/2$ instead of $c=2/3$ (which you found correctly). Also be aware the $D(x)=0$ for $x\leq 0$ and $D(x)=1$ for $x\geq 1$. Use $\mathbb Eg(X)=\int g(x)f(x)dx$ to find the expectation. This for $g(x)=1+x^2/2$.

Comment: @drhab So, for B) it would go something like:
$$E_g(X)=\int_0^1(1+\frac{x^2}{2})(\frac{2}{3}(1+x))$$

Comment: Yes, that is a proper way to deal with it.

Comment: And for C) if I understand correctly from [link](https://www.stat.washington.edu/~nehemyl/files/UW_MATH-STAT395_functions-random-variables.pdf)  
$$F_Y(y) = P((\sqrt{X}-1)<=y) = P(X<=(y+1)^2)=F_X((y+1)^2)=\int_0^{(y+1)^2}\frac{2}{3}(1+x)=...=\frac{2}{3}((y+1)^2+\frac{((y+1)^2)^2}{2})$$  
And then again $f_Y(y)=\frac{d}{dy}F_Y(y)$

Comment: I am too lazy to check whether the final expression is okay but the procedure is correct. This if you keep in mind that for all $y$ with $(y+1)^2\geq1$ the outcome must be $1$ and for all $y$ with $y<-1$ the outcome must be $0$.